# Preciso de ajuda para criar um jogo tipo 21

Tags: python, lista, while, random

estou trabalhando em um jogo tipo 21, e estou com dificuldades de criar uma lógica para que os valores que o usuário receba através de uma sorteio com `random.choice` fiquem armazenados em uma lista e logo em seguida eu exiba o cálculo dos elementos até que o usuário continue pedindo ou até que ele não ultrapasse 21 e então será exibida a mensagem "você perdeu, fez 21 pontos".

eu estou com dificuldades para criar essa lista que vai receber e mostrar o calculo e sendo que seus elementos serão o resultado dos `random.choice` que cada "sim" do usuário resultará...

```
#21 the game

import random

baralho = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]

def dar_cartas():
    listaElementos = [[baralhos]]
    print(random.choice([listaElementos]))
    print(listaElementos)

print("\nBEM-VINDO(A) AO 21")

p1 = str(input("""\nDIGITE
                \n[1] PARA JOGAR
       \n[2] PARA SAIR
       \n"""))
p2 = 0
if p1 == "1":
    print("INICIANDO\n")
elif p1 == "2":
    print("SAINDO\n")
while p1 != "2":
        print("Sua carta é", random.choice(baralho))
        while p2 != "não":
            p2 = str(input("Você quer mais cartas?\n"))
            print("Sua carta é", random.choice(baralho))
        else:
            break           
else:
    pass
```

#isso foi o que consegui fazer até agora, são só esboços...porque eu não consigo fazer essa parte das listas.

Answer (score 1):

A logica que utilizei par foi criar uma variavel para receber todos os valores o `total`:

```
#21 the game

import random

baralho = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10]
tracinhofofo = ('-=')*20

print(f"{tracinhofofo}\n        BEM-VINDO(A) AO JOGO 21!\n{tracinhofofo}")

p1 = int(input("\nDIGITE: \n[1] PARA JOGAR\n[2] PARA SAIR\n>> "))

#Além da decisão de continuar...
#Aqui é uma variavel para receber todos os valores que o random.choice() escolhe.
p2 = total = x = 0

if p1 == "1":
    print("\nINICIANDO...")
elif p1 == "2":
    print("\nSAINDO...\nAté a Proxíma!")

while p2 != "N":
    #Aqui, cada vez que a pessoa continua, o X se torna SOMENTE um valor aleatorio do baralho
    x = random.choice(baralho)

    #O total soma o valor anterior mais o X escolhido na rodada
    total += x

    #O jogo:
    print("\nSua carta é", x)
    p2 = str(input("Você quer mais cartas?\n>> ").upper()) #O .upper() joga o "N" e o "n(minusculo)" == N

    #Se ele não parar antes e o total for MAIOR que 21:
    if total > 21:
        print(f'\nVocê PERDEU!\nAs soma das cartas escolhidas foi {total} e PASSOU de 21!')
        break

    #Se ele não quiser continuar, e parar ANTES do resultado der 21:
    if p2 == 'N':
        print(f'\nPARABÉNS!\n As soma das cartas escolhidas foi {total} e deu menos que 21!')
        break
```

Deixei comentarios para ajudar no esclarecimento,
Dicas:

- Se não tiver utilizado anteriormente aspas, use aspas simples, não duplas logo de primeira, é mais aceito pela comunidade Python, não é errado, mas fica mais bonito visualmente.
- Pesquise por fstring, é uma forma mais facil para citar uma variavel: EX:

`print("O total das cartas foi", total "e Sua carta é", x)`

FSTRING =`print(f"O total das cartas foi {total} e Sua carta é {x}")`